# Deleted Ubuntu partition from Windows 10 now I can't boot at all

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

Hello I had Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed a Dell Inspiron 15.
I wanted to get rid of Ubuntu and deleted the partition from Windows and now it wont boot. It goes to GRUB. What can I do to fix this? I've inserted bootable Windows 10 USB and I dont know how to proceed. Startup repair doesnt work[image]

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? If the latter all you have to do is change the boot order in the firmware back to "Windows bootloader manager". If BIOS then you made a rookie mistake and to correct it you need to boot Windows installation media and repair boot, indeed. What exactly have you tried already?

Comment: Ive tried to select the volume with diskpart like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KV84OabGB08 but Im confused, it dosent seem to do anything, when I restart it goes back to grub/rescue

Comment: Is the Windows 10 preinstalled or did you installed yourself? If preinstalled then it's in UEFI mode. This means you just need to do what commented before and **nothing in your video is applicable**.

Comment: added picture to original post. Im not sure how to proceed now. Volume 2 is the main one with windows 10 that I want to boot from. Volume 3 called WINDOWS10 is the usb drive

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia it is not my laptop, how can I tell?

Comment: Don't you think you know about those things before doing potentially disastrous operations in a machine that's no even yours? All I can see in the screenshot seems to indicate a BIOS /Legacy installation and a wired big FAT32 Partition where supposedly Win10 was installed (?!?). If I were you I would just reinstall Windows 10 properly, assuming you have backups of all the necessary personal files you want to keep.

Comment: The one called "WINDOWS10" is my external usb that I made bootable. The actual Windows 10 installation is in volume 2

Comment: So, it's definitely BIOS/Legacy: Neither my first comment not the answer below is applicable. The instructions in the video are but you must boot from a Windows 10 installation USB and follow the same instructions shown in the video, "fixmbr" and "fixboot" should do it. But also reinstalling may give better results.

Comment: Can I do something to recover files first?

Comment: Maybe, if not encrypted. You can boot any Linux live session and copy files to an external drive. Now, if Windows Fast Startup feature hasn't been disabled prior to this mess you'll have to mount the Windows partition read-only, just clicking it in the files manager won't work, it'll give an error.

Comment: how can I mount the windows partition read only?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I no longer have the ubuntu partition as I deleted it :(

Comment: The instructions are the same for a live session.

Comment: made a bootable ubuntu usb and managed to backup files from the live session!  thank you so much Gabriela :)